# How to validate only when param is exist in express-validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation, express-validator

I'm building a `update user` method in express. The `data` is dynamic.
Like: I have 2 field that can be updated: `name`, `phone_number`,

In 1 request, the data can be only `phone_number` or `name` or both.

I use `express-validator` to validate data:

```
update: [
    check('name').trim().isLength({ min: 3, max: 30 }).bail(),
    (req, res, next) => {
      const errors = validationResult(req)
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) return res.json({ code: 400, message: 'invalid data' })

      next()
    },
  ]
```

When I want to update only `phone_number`, the data won't have `name`.

I want to validate `name` only when data has `name`. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is [`optional`](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/6.14.0/validation-chain-api#optionaloptions).

This will skip validations when the value of `name` is not set (`undefined`):

```
check('name').optional().trim().isLength({ min: 3, max: 30 }),
```

But you can also skip them when the value is `null` *or* `undefined`, like this:

```
check('name').optional({ nullable: true }).trim().isLength({ min: 3, max: 30 }),
```

And finally, if you'd like to skip validations when the value is `null`, `undefined`, `false`, zero *or* an empty string, you can do this:

```
check('name').optional({ checkFalsy: true }).trim().isLength({ min: 3, max: 30 }),
```